# Ajax pagination works only first and third times

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm using ajax-based pagination, heres the markup

```
<div id="portfolio-thumbs">
    <ul id="portfolio-destaque">
        HERE GOES MY LOOP AND CONTENT , some LI's with thumbs and stuff   
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="pagi-container">
    <div id="paginar">
        <?php posts_nav_link(); ?> 
    </div>
</div>
```

the  `<?php posts_nav_link(); ?>` rendered looks like this:

```
<div id="pagi-container">
    <div id="paginar">
        <a href="http://localhost/paulo/page/2/" >next Page &raquo;</a>  
    </div>
</div>
```

then, i use this jquery to load the pagination links:

```
$('#paginar > a').on('click',  function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    jQuery('#portfolio-thumbs').html('Loading...');
    jQuery('#portfolio-thumbs').load(link+' #portfolio-destaque');
    jQuery('#pagi-container').load(link+' #paginar');   
});
```

When I click Next Page link, it loads the content inside `#portfolio-thumbs` with the markup ok, the only difference is the `#pagi-container` that loads this:

```
<div id="pagi-container">
    <div id="paginar">
        <a href="http://localhost/paulo/">« Prev Page</a> — 
        <a href="http://localhost/paulo/page/3/">Next Page »</a>  
    </div>
</div>
```

At this point, Jquery does not work anymore. If I click any pagination link it loads the full page.... In the next page, where it loads only 1 pagination link, it works ok.
My guess is that, somehow, my jquery is only working with 1 `#paginar a`, breaking when there's more than 1 link.... but I'm not sure... anyone have any idea?

Comment: So where do you think the problem is?

Comment: Wordpress loads jQuery in noConflict mode - your call to `$.on()` might be causing problems.

Comment: it is inside a  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) and even this way works only on first page

Comment: also, i tried with .click() instead of .on() and it works on first page and last page (where theres only 1 pagination link) only

Comment: strip down the second page to one link and see if the issue is resolved.

Comment: well, i loaded page/2 via browser, worked ok, then i got <prev and >next links. So i used chrome element inspector and deleted one of the links.... didn't word :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's because you're changing the contents of `#paginar`, so what happens is the event on the links are getting cleared. depending on your jquery version, you can either use `.live()` or add the event to the `#pagi-container` instead:

`$('#pagi-container').on('click','#paginar > a',function()  {... }`